# Opposite of 'If X,Y are independent, Mx+y(t)=Mx(t)My(t)'

Tags: moment-generating-functions

It is known that If X,Y are independent random variables,
Mx+y(t)=Mx(t)My(t)

It's because if X and Y are independent, f(X) and g(Y) are also independent.

How about the opposite?

It X and Y have moment generating function and Mx+y(t) = Mx(t)My(t), then 
X and Y are independent

Comment: I don't think this referrence has an answer to the present question.

Comment: Yes the reference is for a different question